# Kaldi : error loading shared library

Tags: kaldi

My script gets stuck for error in loading shared library

The error log is:

```
online2-wav-nnet3-latgen-faster --do-endpointing=false --frames-per-chunk=20 --extra-left-context-initial=0 --online=false --frame-subsampling-factor=3 --config=exp/tdnn_7b_chain_online/conf/online.conf --min-active=200 --max-active=7000 --beam=15.0 --lattice-beam=6.0 --acoustic-scale=1.0 --word-symbol-table=exp/tdnn_7b_chain_online/graph_pp/words.txt exp/tdnn_7b_chain_online/final.mdl exp/tdnn_7b_chain_online/graph_pp/HCLG.fst ark:exp/tdnn_7b_chain_online/decode_dev/per_utt/utt2spk.1 "ark,s,cs:wav-copy scp,p:audio/temp_output/split1/1/wav.scp ark:- |" "ark:|/home/rohit/kaldi/src/latbin/lattice-best-path --acoustic-scale=1.0 ark:- ark,t:- | utils/int2sym.pl -f 2- data/lang_chain/words.txt >> test.txt" 
Started at Fri May 19 11:12:46 IST 2017

online2-wav-nnet3-latgen-faster: error while loading shared libraries: libfst.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Accounting: time=0 threads=1
Ended (code 127) at Fri May 19 11:12:46 IST 2017, elapsed time 0 seconds
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hello, May I ask did you solve this problem? I encounter the same issue.